# Oracle Trigger - Updating multiple rows on table

Tags: oracle, triggers

If I have a trigger that is executed on updates to TableA, is there an issue if I update 100 records on TableA in one update statement?  I suspect that the trigger will run 100 times for each record.  Is that correct or will it only run once?  I've been warned that updating multiple records on one update statement might cause an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the trigger is defined as `FOR EACH ROW` then it will fire **once** for each row updated, i.e. 100 times in total.  If not `FOR EACH ROW` it will just fire once.

Answer (score 2):

The trigger will run for each record, but it will not necessarily cause any problems. Of course, it depends on what your trigger does.

In some cases, you might use several triggers

1. a BEFORE UPDATE trigger to intialize a collection
2. a BEFORE UPDATE FOR EACH ROW trigger to fill the collection with the IDs of the affected records
3. a AFTER UPDATE trigger to process the collected IDs